# How to specify source directory location in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake

In my c++ cmake project I want my CMakeLists.txt and source files in different locations. How can you specify this to cmake? I want to know this because I believe it makes sense to separate build files from source files.

In my case, this is for a cross platform project. I know one usually uses a single top-level CMakeLists.txt + conditional constructs to handle different targets/platforms, but what I plan is to have different CMakeLists.txt files for each platform and have them AWAY from the sources. Like so:

```
-my_project
   -sources
      -module1
         -common.hpp
         -common.cpp
         -windows
            -win_functions.cpp
            -win_functions.hpp
         -linux
            -linux_functions.cpp
            -linux_functions.hpp
      -module2 (...)
      -module3 (...)
   -build_projects
      -windows
         -CMakeLists.txt
      -linux
         -CMakeLists.txt
```

It seems to me it would be a matter of specifying a new cmake's working/source directory but so far the closet I get is to prepend the correct location when adding source files as in:

```
target_sources(my_target_windows PRIVATE ${win_source_dir}/win_functions.cpp)
```

But the problem is visual studio won't let me preview the source files when adding them in this way, and it seems I cannot solve this in visual studio's CMakeSettings.json either. So I am looking for a more built-in feature for this.

Comment: You're describing issues with your IDE, and that might just be an IDE issue.  Have you tried building?

Comment: *"what I plan is to have different CMakeLists.txt files for each platform"* That's exactly what you should not do.  CMake is a cross-platform build tool, and you should write your CMakeLists.txt so they work on all platforms.  There may be the occasional condition (if/else) inside, but 90% of it should not care about which platform.

Comment: @JohnZwinck ok, say my CMakeLists are prepared to handle all platforms. Still, I would like to have them located away from sources, so as to avoid polluting the source directory with build files. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, you can just reference the source files as relative paths like `src/stuff.cpp`.

Comment: @StephenNewell, maybe my particular problem is solved in the IDE, yes, in which case IDE-solutions are welcomed. And yes, I've tried building but VS is still not showing anything in the solution explorer... and it is a pain.
But I think the issue stands even outside my contrived example: separation of cmake and source files (other than prefixing relative/absolute paths to sources, as described)

Comment: @JohnZwinck is that the only way? because I've tried this, but IDE won't show sources in solution explorer, as described.

Comment: Does the build actually work (i.e. is it just a presentation issue)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck yes, build works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a fix for my problem within Visual Studio:

In solution explorer set "solutions and folders" to "CMake Targets View" and it will now correctly display sources and headers added to the cmake project.

So, using relative paths to sources in cmake + this VS feature solves my problem.